# Application Command versus Custom Command (through Relay Pattern)

Tags: wpf, command

Have a quick theoretical question - if somebody can help answer:

The application commands which WPF provides - are they technically useless (or should not be leveraged) **specifically in MVVM pattern** since the Custom Commands (Relay Command Pattern) is used in all cases. That's what my reading seems to indicate but wanted to get some thoughts on this.

[MSDN Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.applicationcommands.aspx)

If not - can somebody please also point to a quick code sample of application commands and its correct usage within MVVM pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what you're asking; the `ApplicationCommands` is a set of commom commands that an application might need to make use of, so I wouldn't say they're useless but they have specific usages which in many applications are probably not useful.  Personally I've never used them.

I think you will find that a lot (me included) of people that write WPF applications using the MVVM pattern will use some variation of the [`DelegateCommand`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg431410%28v=PandP.40%29.aspx), and as evidence I would offer that most of the MVVM frameworks offer an implementation of such.

Comment: Thanks - thats pretty much what I have been doing myself - using DelegateCommand/Relay Pattern. The reason for the question was because the same things that Application Commands help us get - can be implemented through the above pattern (with more control etc) - so wanted to clarify. But your answer definitely helps